# readLines with connection or simply path in R

Tags: html, r, connection

I'm using readLines to get the content of the HTML files from web. 
 Is it necessary to first open a connection:

```
con <- url("http://google.com", open = "r")
readLines(con)
close(con)
```

or can I simply do:

```
readLines("http://google.com")
```

Both approaches seem to work and produce the same results. Second seems to be better since doesn't require opening and closing the connection. Is there any reason the first approach is superior?

Comment: Please read `?readLines`.

Answer (score 1):

The `readLines` call will work, but note that its prototype does not include the `...` argument. This means you would be unable to pass in any arguments specific to opening a URL -- for example, the `method` parameter.

In my experience it's better to be explicit if the 'out of the box' defaults may not work for some sites.